# Extracting values from csv-parser in syslog-ng

Tags: syslog, syslog-ng

I've got a syslog feed in csv format being ingested by syslog-ng using the csv-parser and written to disk.

As I understand it, using the csv-parser is supposed to give syslog-ng context into the data coming in and what value means what.  I'd like to use that context to make syslog-ng apply filters based on that logic.

For example, I'd like it to only log an event to disk if one of the csv columns match a specific value.

The csv-parser [documentation](https://www.balabit.com/documents/syslog-ng-ose-latest-guides/en/syslog-ng-ose-guide-admin/html/csv-parser.html) seems to suggest this should be possible.

My config looks a little like:

```
parser p_my_app {
    csv-parser(
        columns("MY_APP.COLOUR","MY_APP.SIZE","MY_APP.SERIAL_NUMBER")
        delimiters(",")
        flags(escape-double-char)
    );
};

source s_my_app {
    syslog(ip(0.0.0.0) port(6514)
        transport("tcp")
    );
}; 

filter f_my_app { 
    match("123456" value("MY_APP.SERIAL_NUMBER") );
};

destination d_my_app { 
    file("/var/log/my_app.log"
        create_dirs(yes)
    ); 
};

log { 
    source(s_my_app);
    filter(f_my_app);
    parser(p_my_app);
    destination(d_my_app); 
};
```

However, it seems no matter how much I try, the match never matches. Here's the sylog-ng debug output with that config:

```
Incoming log entry; line='<14>1 2017-01-18T17:46:38+11:00 hostname  - - - red,large,123456
'
Filter rule evaluation begins; rule='f_my_app', location='/etc/syslog-ng/conf.d/my-app.conf:16:18'
Filter node evaluation result; result='not-match'
Filter rule evaluation result; result='not-match', rule='f_my_app', location='/etc/syslog-ng/conf.d/my-app.conf:16:18'
```

I (hope?) I'm missing something really obvious, but I can't find any complete examples online after hours of Googling, just extracts which never seem to work.  Is anyone able to see what I'm doing wrong and/or supply a complete working example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as seems to always be the way, I spend a week on a problem, give up, decide to seek help -- then figure out the solution myself an hour later.

My issue was the order of the items in the `log()` statement.  Specifically, the `parser()` line **MUST** be before the `filter()` statement.

Indeed, the [documentation](https://www.balabit.com/documents/syslog-ng-ose-latest-guides/en/syslog-ng-ose-guide-admin/html/csv-parser.html) (which I must have read 10 times and missed) states that:

> **Note**
>   The order of filters, rewriting rules, and parsers in the log statement is important, as they are processed sequentially.

So, the working code is to use:

```
log { 
    source(s_my_app);
    parser(p_my_app);
    filter(f_my_app);
    destination(d_my_app); 
};
```

Also, one other thing to note is that `match()` actually is supposed to be a regex, so for added clarity, I've also updated the filter to:

```
filter f_my_app { 
    match("123456" value("MY_APP.SERIAL_NUMBER") type("string"));
};
```

With syslog-ng now reporting:

```
Incoming log entry; line='<14>1 2017-01-18T17:46:38+11:00 hostname  - - - red,large,123456
'
Message parsing complete; result='1', rule='p_my_app', location='/etc/syslog-ng/conf.d/my-app.conf:14:2'
Filter rule evaluation begins; rule='f_my_app', location='/etc/syslog-ng/conf.d/my-app.conf:16:18'
Filter node evaluation result; result='match'
Filter rule evaluation result; result='match', rule='f_my_app', location='/etc/syslog-ng/conf.d/my-app.conf:16:18'
```